# $pscmdlet.ShouldProcess(...) returns "Yes" or "Yes to All"

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to create VMs, and obviously I would like to support the standard confirm/whatif semantics. However, if I have a number of machines to create, it would be good if I could differentiate between "Yes" and "Yes to All" so I don't necessarily have to reconfirm every machine.

$pscmdlet.ShouldProcess only returns a boolean, so how can I tell the difference?

Comment: I could use $psCmdlet.ShouldContinue(string, caption, yesToAll, noToAll) but that doesn't support confirmImpact and whatif.

Comment: Oh, and another thing - I was hoping to use yes vs yes to all to prompt for additional confirmation if the user appeared to be being cavalier about creating many VMs in a low-resource situation.
I guess that's not feasible in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example function that accepts pipeline input for the computer name and implements the behaviour you desire:

```
function set-something {
    [cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
    param(
        [parameter(position=0, valuefrompipeline=$true)]
        $Computer,
        [parameter(position=1)]
        $Value
    )

    process {
        if ($pscmdlet.shouldprocess("Are you sure?")) {        
            write-host "setting machine $computer to $value"
        }
    }
}

"srv1","srv2","srv3" | set-something -value 42 -confirm
```

If you answer "yes" you will be prompted for the next machine. If you answer "yes to all" you will no longer be prompted. The important part is that you use pipeline input - this causes the function to be executed as a whole only *once*, but the process block within the function is invoked once for *each* incoming element in the pipeline. This lets it remember the "yes for all" and will not prompt on subsequent process block invocations. Make sense?

UPDATE: it's not required to use a pipeline for this to work. The important thing is that the function must be able to keep state, so passing all input in an array or collection as a parameter would work too. In this case, you would loop over the $computer collection yourself. With a pipeline, effectively the shell loops for you.

Comment: I'm perfectly clear on the implementation, thank you. What was not clear to me from the docs is that this is expected to *always* be used in the context of a pipeline.

Comment: The pipeline comment is only pertaining to my example. You can do it without pipeline too, where all of the input is passed as an argument. My main point is that the function is invoked only once so it can keep state.

Comment: I have some code where I could not put the `ShouldProcess` in the outer loop, but wanted it in the inner function instead. So I passed in `$pscmdlet` to the inner function, and called `ShouldProcess` on that instead. Then the state is stored in the outer loop's context, and yes/no-all works.